# Quirky Bootstrap Menu Toggle behavior

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

When you open the page, I have a navbar to display a slogan and is the bar that the toggler button is upon. There is a second navbar that is the target of the toggler button. It displays as a side menu. You must click the toggler button 2 times to get the menu to start toggling correctly.

```html
    <style>
    #menu li a {
      line-height: 22px;
      height: 22px;
      width: 160px;
      background-size: auto;
      text-align: right;
      padding-top: 0px;
      color: #eee;
    }

    #menu {
      min-width: 210px;
    }

    .fa-bars {
      color: white;
    }

    .businessAddress li {
       list-style-type: none;
       font-size: 14px;
       text-align: right;
       margin: 0;
       color: #eee;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <h1>
          Company Header
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar bg-success">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="False" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
        </button>
        <h2 class="mx-auto">
           Slogan
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="navbar bg-success" id="menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="navItem active"><a href="#">Home Link</a></li>
               <li class="navItem"><a href="#">Services Link</a></li>
               <li class="navItem"><a href="#">Contact Link</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="businessAddress d-none d-md-block">
              <li>&nbsp;</li>
              <li>Company Name</li>
              <li>Street Address</li>
              <li>City, ST Zip</li>
              <li>&nbsp;</li>
              <li>123-456-7890</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The behavior is that when you first open the page, the menu navbar is already displayed. This is the desired behavior. But you have to hit the toggler button 2 times to get the side menu to collapse and it does collapse on the second go. And it will properly expand/collapse after this point. However, if you go to a different link on the menu or refresh the page the toggler button requires 2 clicks to start working correctly.

Any thoughts on how can I get the toggle to start off working right away?

Much appreciated,
Kent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `collapse show` classes to the second navbar. The HTML for the second navbar should be `<div class="navbar bg-success collapse show" id="menu">`

Comment: Bless you Fathima! I am not sure how you knew to do this, but it works brilliantly. Thanks, Kent